# How to make a Container stretch to occupy same height as row?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to achieve something like below[image]

What I am able to achieve

[image]

Here is my code

```
return Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 4,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.alarm),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 2,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Starts",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowMedium", fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        studentClassesData.classStarttime,
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold", fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "to",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowMedium", fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        studentClassesData.classEndtime,
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold", fontSize: 12),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      studentClassesData.subject,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "BarlowBold", fontSize: 12, color: blue),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage:
                            NetworkImage(studentClassesData.facultyImage),
                        child: Image.asset("images/round_only.webp"),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5,),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "Faculty",
                              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "KohinoorDemi"),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 3,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            studentClassesData.faculty,
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.business),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Floor/Room",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "KohinoorDemi"),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 3,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "${studentClassesData.floor}/${studentClassesData.room}",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
```

I am not able to achieve the view which has a yellowish colour at the start to occupy same height as the Row. As you can see in the above code I have used a `Container` and I know I can give a height to the container  but I don't want to give a fixed height to the container as the height may change depending on data coming from the api..

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but the container is inside a Row, so if I wrap it inside Expanded it will stretch horizontally and not vertically

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer does not work, btw I want to expand the height of the container and also not give it a fixed value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use - `IntrinsicHeight`  to get what you want.

working Code(with Dummy Values):

```
 Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    width: 4,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 5.0,),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.alarm),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Starts",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "BarlowMedium", fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '11:30 AM',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold", fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "to",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "BarlowMedium", fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '1:30 PM',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold", fontSize: 12),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          'Design Studio 6 (Capstone)',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "BarlowBold",
                              fontSize: 12,
                              color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage:
                                NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any'),
                            child: Image.asset("images/round_only.webp"),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  "Faculty",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "KohinoorDemi"),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 3,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Meenal',
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold"),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.business),
                          Text(
                            "Floor/Room",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "KohinoorDemi"),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 3,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "6th Floor: North Wing / ISDI 606",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold"),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )),
```

Output:
I don't have fonts you have used, so UI looks different than yours. But it get the job Done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by wrapping your `Card` in a `SizedBox` giving it a height you want. In this case, you don't need to hard code any height to your `Container`, the `Container` will just expand to match the height of your `Row`. Here is simple example:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 100,
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 100, // no need to set any height, it will automatically fill to match row
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: not sure if hardcoding height to sized box is a good idea as the data I am receiving is dynamic